# Can Anyone Say How To print a html template using printer in angular2?

Tags: html, angular, types

There is A html template in my Angular2 component. What i want to do is, When I click on print button That is in same html page, it should perform the print function(like- displaying print preview, Proceed and print, etc).
So, Can Anyone You tell me how to print an html template in Angular2?

Comment: There is not Angular2 specific printing approach for this, you can simply use JavaScript: `window.print()`.

Comment: thank you :). But, window.print() isn't working. It just prints a part of my HTML template. I wanna print the whole template.:(

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379274/print-html-template-in-angular-2-ng-print-in-angular-2/41379912#41379912

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<button click="window.print();">Print this page</button>
```