# Angular 2- DOM element manipulation in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dom

```
<head>
<script>
function printContent(el){
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
</script>
```

`

How I can use this script in my component class method.I want when My button is clicked my above script is run but I don't know how manipulation DOM in Angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to wrap it within a `script` HTML tag, just call that function (implemented in your TS file) once the button is clicked, something like: `<button (click)="printContent()">print</button>` .
If you're looking for **print** stuffs, [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379274/print-html-template-in-angular-2-ng-print-in-angular-2/41379912#41379912) could help you.