# Angular 2 printing a component

Tags: angular

In plain JavaScript, you are able to print an element by getting the element ID, putting it in a new window, and using window.print().

What is the "Angular 2" way to do such a thing? I have gotten as far as getting a ViewChild of the component I wish to print, but I'm not sure how to access its html and subsequently print it, or if that's even what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Html template in Angular 2 (ng-print in Angular 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379274/print-html-template-in-angular-2-ng-print-in-angular-2)

Comment: The best way i found is create your print component, give it a route to highest hierachy on your routing. Open the route with window.open(url). And on that component afterviewinit call window.print() . You can include any of your component into print component after the view created print it. Dont forget to add css @media print{} on the print component.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print some custom HTML, this method doesn't need a new window.

ts:

```
    let control_Print;

    control_Print = document.getElementById('__printingFrame');

    let doc = control_Print.contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write("<div style='color:red;'>I WANT TO PRINT THIS, NOT THE CURRENT HTML</div>");
    doc.close();

    control_Print = control_Print.contentWindow;
    control_Print.focus();
    control_Print.print();
```

html:

```
<iframe title="Lets print" id="__printingFrame" style="width: 0; height: 0; border: 0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -3):

**HTML**

```
    <div id="printSection"></div>
    <button (click)="print()">PRINT</button>
```

**TS**

```
    print(): void {
       let printContents, popupWin;
       printContents = document.getElementById('printSection').innerHTML;
       popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
       popupWin.document.open();
       popupWin.document.write(`
          <html>
              <head>
                  <title>Print tab</title>
                  <style>
                      //........Customized style.......
                  </style>
              </head>
              <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}
              </body>
          </html>`
       );
       popupWin.document.close();
    }
```

Comment: Ok. I can understand why someone would downvote this answer (for a multitude of reasons) but .. this is the perfect hammer right now!

Comment: It's just copypaste of accepted answer from similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379274/print-html-template-in-angular-2-ng-print-in-angular-2