# Angular 2 : Generating Word and pdf from template

Tags: angular, ms-word, pdf-generation, documentation-generation

I have a Word template with some fields to fill and I would like to use this template in my Angular 2 application to generate the same Word document with fields filled (with an object).

As I take the data from a database, I need absolutely to use an object coming from a service and I need to use a particular template.

I saw that there were some APIs like office-js, jsPDF, etc... but I don't know which one to choose and I don't know how to use them.

What do you guys recommend?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379274/print-html-template-in-angular-2-ng-print-in-angular-2

Comment: Not exactly. I don't want the word template to be the template of the component. I want it to be generated and being downloadable apart @Arjun

Comment: You mentioned Javascript libraries.  Do you need to do the template population client side in Javascript?