# Angular 4 printing a modal window

Tags: angular, printing, bootstrap-modal, printing-web-page

I want to print a modal window with data that I get from a service. So far I have read about some CSS methods that hide other elements on @media print, but I have not quite understand how or where to use this.

Anyone has had any experience printing this modal windows in angular 2+?

Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Comment: You should add some details about what you are trying to achieve. Maybe some code sample. Which CSS libraries you have already tried. Anything that can help to start somewhere. In the state, we can not really help without writing all the code for you...

Comment: i use   ng-bootstrap for modals , it works great

Comment: I am using ng2-bootstrap-modals for creating modals, but my question goes on how to print them without printing any other parts of the page.

Comment: Noémi I do not intent to have the code written for me, so far I haven't tried any CSS libraries, I have been trying to write the code myself, I read I have to hide all the code but the modal in order to print it. What I was hoping was to get some clues as what CSS to use and where should I place it.

Comment: These questions are becoming terrible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379274/print-html-template-in-angular-2-ng-print-in-angular-2