# Create a custom pdf document with Angular

Tags: angular, pdf

Anyone knows a proper way to print a PDF document based on data i am getting from a backend provider?

I have tried using this solution [Print Html template in Angular 2 (ng-print in Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379274/print-html-template-in-angular-2-ng-print-in-angular-2) , but it's not always convinient, mainly because am manipulating large data with various directives (such as *ngFor) that cannot be used some aspects of that solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best done on the server side.  I would create a webservice that generates a PDF then call it from the angular app.  There are a ton of frameworks to generate PDFs on server side tech.  Itext itesxtsharp etc.

Comment: i frogot to mention that i am using spring boot, do you know a good framework for that matter?

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote?  Please explain to me why it's wrong for me to recommend this be done on the server....