# Print functionality in Angular4 - reactive form values are not shown

Tags: angular

I am using a reactive form in Angular4. I want to implement print functionality for the same. However, the reactive form values are not shown while printing. How can I achieve this? Posting my code below:

html

```
<section id="print-section">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-child input-wrap">
            <span>Date</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Date" class="borderStyle form-control" formControlName="date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-child input-wrap">
            <span>Address</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Address" class="borderStyle form-control" formControlName="address">
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

ts

```
let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>
          </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
```

Comment: why are you not using **myForm** to print elements value? Add more code specific to your ts

Comment: I am trying to print the page.

Comment: check update you are missing approch

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
```

is incorrect as per coding , that is reason my below answer is not working. if you are using reactive form approach then you should create from in your ts file like as below

```
export class HeroDetailComponent3 {
  printContents: FormGroup; 

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { // <--- inject FormBuilder
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.printContents= this.fb.group({
      date: '', 
      address: ''
    });
  }
}
```

check here for detail : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

---

if you want form value the do like this

```
 const json = JSON.stringify( this.printContents.value );
 <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${json }</body>
```

or try out

I am not sure but you might need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer), as you are trying to put html elements from angular.

Comment: I got undefined when I did this.

Comment: still the same.

Comment: @RemyaJ have you used snitizer and can you share your full ts file code

Comment: No I already have a form and formcontrol names and all of that. The values are not shown in the print preview