# how to customize angular4 page print on clicking ctrl+p

Tags: angular, css, angular5

I have an angular4 app, on pressing ctrl+p on browser I need to customize the print page view instead default view. The page which I need to print has only angular components, I tried by writing @media print in each component css but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar case in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379274/print-html-template-in-angular-2-ng-print-in-angular-2). They have an example on angularJS and angular.

Then, you can check the ctrl+p key press by access to [this](https://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events/) post.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a plugin called [printThis.js](https://plugins.jquery.com/printThis/) and save lots of coding time.

Add the script to your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/printThis/1.14.0/printThis.min.js"></script>
```

Add the print button and give it an `id` you'll use with printThis:

```
<button id="print-button-id" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Print</button>
```

Then use this script to print your page:

```
$('#print-button-id').on("click", function () {
      $('#print-section-id').printThis({
            debug: false,
            importCSS: true,
            importStyle: true,
            printContainer: true,
            loadCSS: "your-custom-style-for-printing.css",
            pageTitle: "Your print title",
            removeInline: false,
            printDelay: 333,
            header: null,
            formValues: true
      });
});
```

Finally, as you can see from the script, it's printing the element with the `id="print-section-id"`, so you'll want to use in place of that the id of the element that encloses the section you want to print.