# Problem with image printing using ngx-print

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

Image is not getting printed with ngx-print. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

**HTML**

```
<button  type="button" printTitle="PrintVoucher" [useExistingCss]="true" 
                                        printSectionId="printVoucher" ngxPrint>
                                        Print </button>
```

---

```
<div row id="printVoucher" >
 <img  src="assets/images/logo.png">
</div>
```

However the image is visible on the screen , but not visible in the print preview section.

[image]

Comment: I can clearly see the image is broken on the page as well behind the print preview.

Comment: Yes..that is the problem..but the original page has the logo

Comment: check the image path ? is it coming dynamic or static

Answer (score 2):

you have to use absolute path , Not relative path

ie your path should be for example

"http://localhost:3000/assets/images/print-logo.png"
not "print-logo.png"

[to know the difference between relative and absolute path check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript)

to get your current base Url for example ("http://localhost:3000")  you can use

let x = window.location.origin;

Comment: are you sure that that path of your source the same path ?!!
can you send me print screen for your browser Sources and  other for path on browser Element

Answer (score 0):

I already faced this problem , i've noticed that in the last one , the printable page , after inspecting it,the directory is not the right one , he was adding the directory of the page that i was printing from , so how to fix this ? i just added a `DomSanitizer`.

in your case, I think that something like this should work: ( notice that i added `/` at the begining of your link )

```
<img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('/assets/images/logo.png')" />
```

Add sanitizer to you constructor :

```
 import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser"; 

 export class AppComponent {
      constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem before, I only did the following:

image path was: assets/img/logo.png
changed it into: /assets/img/logo.png

Just added a `/` at the beginning of the path and it worked.