# Images not displaying when print using ngx-print library

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

As you can see , the images are shown correctly in the screen :

[image]

but when i try to print this container using [ngx-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print) it's not displaying correctly :

[image]

**Very important :**  I have no control over the images because they come from the back-end.

HTML :

```
<div class="hover-div">
    <button mat-button class="title-div" printSectionId="card-container" 
         printTitle="professionalcard" [useExistingCss]="true" ngxPrint>
            <div fxLayout="row">
                <mat-icon class="preview-icon">print</mat-icon>
                <div>print</div>
            </div>
     </button>
</div>
```

HTML of images :

```
<div class="simple-image" *ngIf="cardModel[r.content].value">
    <img [src]="cardModel[r.content].value"
        class="image-holder1">
</div>
```

Here is the result when i inspect the `img` in the page :

[image]

and this one , when i inspect the page viewer when printing :

[image]

i've noticed that in the last one , the link is not the right one , he is adding the directory of the page that i'm printing from , so how to fix this ?

Comment: It's probably because you are using background images. Browers do not print them by default. Here are some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670151/how-can-i-force-browsers-to-print-background-images-in-css

Comment: no , it's not a background , it's an `<img>` , by the way .. i already set `-webkit-print-color-adjust` to `exact`

Comment: Can you show the html for images?

Comment: i added it to the question

Comment: Are there any errors in chrome console. Alternatively, right click on the image > inspect  > browse to the image URL > copy it > paste it to new tab and check if the image is loading. If not issue with image path !!

Comment: no , the images are loading correclty, links of the images work when i open them in a new tab

Comment: Could you add `{{cardModel[r.content].value}}` next to the image to make sure this value is set with thee correct value when printing?

Comment: if you add `{{ }}` , then you need to get off the binding `[ ]` , it comes back to the same result . the image is displaying very well

Comment: @mightyteja see the screenshots i added

Comment: a quick search lead me to this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694343/problem-with-image-printing-using-ngx-print. Kindly try updating the path

Comment: the problem is that i'm using a proxy to redirect the endpoint , so even if i add localhost:4200 it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57240721/4536543) answer and [this](https://github.com/selemxmn/ngx-print/issues/45#issuecomment-514858415) GitHub issue comment, you have to use absolute path for the image.

So, in your case, I think that something like this should work:

```html
<img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('/' + cardModel[r.content].value)" />
```

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
}
```

Comment: I already used the stainizer, but I never thought of using it in such a case !! now it's working great ^^ , thank's !!

Comment: I'm glad that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add let  `window.location.origin`  to make it an absolute path , then you'll not have this problem

Comment: Thank's , its working like that , but i prefer not to use an `absolute path`.